# the role of backbone router

Tags: backbone.js, router

This is a quote from Derick Baileys blog ( creator of Backbone.Marionette):

> But a router should never instantiate a view and manipulate the DOM
>   directly with jQuery or placing the view in to the DOM

But I keep seeing code like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":home
    },
    home: function(){
        // instance of a view object in a router
        var homeView = new HomeView({model:model});
        // do something with homeView 

    })
```

Can this be considered anti-pattern, although it is widely used ?
From my perspective, it is a good idea to separate **definiton** from **instantiation** of objects (calling **new HomeView()** later). But does this is to be found in **router** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone else asked the same question in the comments of the [article you are referring to](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/27/the-responsibilities-of-the-various-pieces-of-backbone-js/). Here is the answer Derick gave to which I agree, I am copying it in order to keep things centralized.

These two examples are functionally the same:

#### example 1

```
Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "foo": "showFoo"
  },

  showFoo: function(){
    var fooView = new FooView();
    fooView.render();
    $("#someEl").html(fooView.el);
  }
});
```

#### example 2

```
Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "foo": "showFoo"
  },

  showFoo: function(){
    FooApp.show();
  }
});

FooApp = {
  show: function(){
    var fooView = new FooView();
    fooView.render();
    $("#someEl").html(fooView.el);
  }
}
```

The difference between the two is coupling, cohesion, encapsulation, separation of concerns and the single responsibility principle. If I want to change how the FooApp shows the application's views and make things work, I shouldn't have to change the Router. These two concerns should be separated. I should have "one reason to change" for the router and for the FooApp (high level application object).

For a small demo app, #1 is ok. Anything more than 1 or 2 views, though, and the code becomes unmaintainable quickly. Having to sift through all of the cruft of doing the actual display so that you can see what the router is doing as a whole is a really bad idea in my experience.

For a larger example of this at play, check out my BBCloneMail sample project: http://github.com/derickbailey... - look at the BBCloneMail.Router.js file.

Comment: You are right - I wasn't reading comments. Anyway I like your clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer initialize all view only once in router.initialize() and then just render them in routing methods. But I don't think it make such a big difference.